# Проверить сколько времени объект соприкасаться с другим

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно проверить если один объект соприкасаться с другим больше 3 секунд то выполнить код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это вполне возможно.

```
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision col)
{
    //если нужно то ставим тут проверку на то соприкасается с нужным объектом или нет
    StartCoroutine(TimerTick);
}

private IEnumerable TimerTick()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    //делаете что хотите после того как время истечет
}
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно